# Why React.DOM is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React 16.5.2
I am learning React by a book and try to use the factories of the "clear" React (i.e. not in JSX). I try to use one of React built factories but I get the problem:

```
(() => {    
    const my_h1 = React.DOM.h1(null,"Stuff") // TypeError: Cannot read property 'h1' of undefined
    ReactDOM.render(my_h1,document.getElementById('root'))
})()
```

Why does it happen?

**UPD**

This is the screen of the **Learning React Functional Web Development with React and Redux** book:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that React.DOM does not exist (but yes ReactDOM, which is not the same), and also ReactDOM.h1 doesn't exist neither. If you want to create an element you should use createElement from React. Here you have the methods available for ReactDOM: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html

Comment: I added **UPD** section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make use of `React.createElement` to create an element instead of `React.DOM`

```
(() => {    
    const my_h1 = React.createElement('h1',null,"Stuff")
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(my_h1),document.getElementById('root'))
})()
```

Also with the latest version in React, React.DOM is no longet valid, you instead need to include the `Dom-factories` with this script

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom-factories@1.0.0/index.js"></script>
```

Then everywhere replace `React.DOM` with `ReactDOMFactories`

**e.g**

```
ReactDOMFactories.h1(null, "Hello World!")
```

This change was introduced around version 15.6.0 in June 2017.

Comment: I tried it before I posted my question and I got the error: ***TypeError: ReactDOM.h1 is not a function***

Comment: It seems what you want to do is to create an element. In such a case, you would make use of React.createElement instead of ReactDOM

Comment: I know about `React.createElement` and I haven't problem with it. I added **UPD** section.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is:

```js
(() => {
    const my_h1 = React.createElement("h1", null, "Stuff");
    ReactDOM.render(my_h1, document.getElementById('root'));
})()
```

Comment: I know about `React.createElement` and I haven't problem with it. I added **UPD** section.